# EventSubscriber Reflection Exception, Class does and doesn't exist

Tags: 8

A reflection error that shouldn't be happening?

Snippets:
mymodule/mymodule.services.yml

```
services:
  mymodule.example_ex:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\ExampleEx
    arguments:
      - '@path.matcher'
      - '@current_user'
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

mymodule/src/EventSubscriber/ExampleEx.php

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class ExampleEx implements EventSubscriberInterface {
  //
}
```

Resulting in the fatal with the message: `ReflectionException: Class Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\ExampleEx does not exist in ReflectionClass->__construct()`, I've tried a variety of re-namings to no avail.

By Commenting the `tags` key value pair from the `services.yml`, no ReflectionExeption occurs. But, no subscriber event occurs either..

Could it be that an unconventional class name (example): `EEEExample` is causing this issue?

I've gone over the code multiple times, rechecking to ensure that names are consistent and I did so again whilst rewriting the actual names for this question.

Comment: Near certainly something is going wrong with my localhost/pc, ignore this...

Comment: I don't know if it's an error in what you wrote here or in your code but there's an apostrophe at the end of your line 3 in your services.yml

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I just checked, I made a mistake while transcribing.. What's also odd, is that on one reload, after copy pasting from a working version. It had dumped my event onRespond as expected. On retries it started failing again. 

I will attempt to reinstall the module onto a new site & hosting installation and get back with an update.

Comment: I clean installed the server, installed the module & dependencies, resulting in a DatabaseException due to the max_allowed_packet size being breached. By raising the max_allowed_packet I have the event subscriber working again. Also, as a baseline for others, comment & uncomment the `tags:` key value pair to do tests of your event subscriber.